# Mappings for compiling and viewing LaTeX documents in Vim

Tags: vim, latexmk

I used to use [LaTeX-Box plugin](https://github.com/latex-box-team/latex-box) to compile and view LaTeX documents with [these mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48622447/7952358).

But I don't use it anymore because `\begin` and `\end` highlighting (and to a lower degree parentheses matching), which can't be turned off, make Vim a lot slower in big `.tex` files.

I know how to create an alternative mappings for compiling `.tex` documents:

```
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <F2> :!latexmk -xelatex %<cr>
autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> <F2> <Esc>:!latexmk -xelatex %<cr>a
```

But this will create output files in directory I am currently in, not in the directory where `.tex` file is (for example, if I am in `~/Desktop` and I open in Vim a file which is in `~/Documents`, if I press `F2`, `.pdf` and all other files are created in `~/Desktop` instead of in `~/Documents`).

I don't know how to create mappings for viewing the compiled `.pdf` document.

So, I am asking you to help me create mappings that will compile `.tex` file, and view created `.pdf` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily modify your mappings to generate files in the same directory as your source file with `:help filename-modifiers`:

```
augroup LaTeX
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <F2> :!cd %:p:h && latexmk -xelatex %<cr>
    autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> <F2> <Esc>:!cd %:p:h && latexmk -xelatex %<cr>a
augroup END
```

To open the generated file with an imaginary `pdfviewer` program (command shortened for legibility):

```
!cd %:p:h && latexmk -xelatex % && pdfviewer %:p:r.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
augroup LaTeX
        autocmd!
        autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <F2> :!cd '%:p:h' && latexmk -xelatex '%:t'<CR>
        autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> <F2> <Esc>:!cd '%:p:h' && latexmk -xelatex '%:t'<CR>a
        autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <F3> :silent !mupdf '%:p:r.pdf'&<CR>
        autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> <F3> <Esc>:silent !mupdf '%:p:r.pdf'&<CR>a
augroup END
```

This is what worked for me. Thanks to [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) for [helping me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335402/7952358) to figure it out.